# Go to report action not working in SSRS web but works inside Report Builder 2.0

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, reportbuilder

First and foremost, I've been saddled with this project because our SQL and reporting guy recently quit.  I've never had exposure to SSRS or Report Builder (and limited SQL experience) but I seem to be muddling through it ok so far.  I've gotten to the point of publishing the new reports on the SSRS server and have run into the following problem.

I use a field in the primary report with the "Go to report" action to open up another report (also published) for more details.  It works properly from within ReportBuilder (2.0) using the report server and I can go to and from the secondary report as I expect.  Its passing the correct parameters to the second report and its runs.

But when I the reports from the SSRS web, the Go To link no longer works.  Mouse hover shows its still a link but clicking goes no where.  I can run both reports independently from SSRS and they still work.

I've tried this in IE and Chrome with no luck in either.  I also poked around at Compatability view and popup blocker but nothing made any difference.

Thanks
JW

Answer (score 0):

You must pay special attention to the absolute and relative paths used in the "Specify a Report" field. Please see this [MSDN article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd220423.aspx) for details on absolute and relative paths.

Comment: Thanks for the article.  I've confirmed that I'm using the full path for the subreport as it relates to the reporting server.  I also use the "browse" to select the subreport for the go to function which, according to the article, is the best way to select the report.

Comment: No I'm afraid that was not the problem

Answer (score 0):

I finally found something that at least alluded to the problem that I was seeing.  I didn't have any indent set in the box or on the page at all but it appears that there was a conflict between the CSS and the html for the link.  [msdn.microsoft.com](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/56a33cf8-ffaa-4329-8703-9666ea4b2713/ssrs-2008-go-to-report-function-fails-when-report-deployed-on-server?forum=sqlreportingservices)

I was able to work around the problem by recreating the information in a simple list text box vs. trying to use a table matrix.